# Applying formula basis of context/Sting in Libra Calc

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have set of formula/formulas for extracting particular data sting from the data set. However i require help in applying multiple formula basis of string contained in data set for extraction.

```
Data Set > Contains string > Formula 1+Formula 2 > Result
```

A1 > ABC/23902983109/ASDJCNKS@YD (Data set) > ABC(String) > IF(SEARCHB("ABC/",A1,1),"ABC") - Formula > ABC (End Result)

A2 > MB/NEFT DR/XYZ/SDSDC098098/DD > NEFT DR(sting) > IF(SEARCHB("/NEFT DR/",A2,1),MID(A2,12,100)) +                                                                                                    LEFT(A2,FIND("/",A2)-1) > XYZ(End Result)

A3 > DCSD CHARGES > CHARGES(String) > IF(SEARCHB("Charges",A3,1),"Charges") > Charges (End Result).

Answer (score 0):

Let's solve this problem together, step by step.

The three examples that you showed in the text of the question show that the problem will be solved if the result will be a fixed text or some part of the original string. First of all, let's create a small helper table - a reference of contexts to which the formula will react in a certain way.

Let's head the first column **Context** (for example, in cell `Q1`) and list in it all the keywords that uniquely determine the type of action with the original string - ABC, NEFT DR, CHARGES, and so on.

Now in a separate cell (for example, in cell `P1`) enter the formula `=TEXTJOIN("|";1;$Q$2:$Q$400)`. The result of executing this function will be a string like as **ABC|NEFT DR|CHARGES**.

In the cell next to the data being processed (for example, in `B1`), enter the formula `=REGEX(A1;$P$1)` and stretch it down. If everything is done correctly, then the result should be like this:
[image: Step 1]

In other words, for each source string its "category" is defined.

Let's continue filling in the original table. Let's add two more columns **Find** and **Replace**.

For context ("category") `ABC`, the search string will be `^.*$` ("Any value"), the replacement string will be `ABC`.
For `CHARGES`, the search string will be the same and the replacement string is `Charges`

Indeed, these are the simplest cases when the belonging of the source string to one of the categories immediately determines the result.

A slightly more complicated case of `NEFT DR` - here the search string can be described as

`^.*NEFT DR/([^/]*)/.*$`

*"somewhere there are words **NEFT DR**, after them a slash, **(then some characters)** up to the next slash"*. Pay attention to the parentheses. If you specify `$1` as the replacement string, then this part will be the result of the replacement.

Let's test our table. Enter the formula `=REGEX(A1;VLOOKUP(B1;$Q$2:$S$400;2;0);VLOOKUP(B1;$Q$2:$S$400;3;0))`

in cell `C1` and stretch it down. The result should be like this

[image: Step 2]

Now in the last formula, instead of both `B1`s, substitute the function from `B1` and wrap all this in the `IFERROR()` function.

```
=IFERROR(REGEX(A1;VLOOKUP(REGEX(A1;$P$1);$Q$2:$S$400;2;0);VLOOKUP(REGEX(A1;$P$1);$Q$2:$S$400;3;0));"")
```

[image: Final]